# insert elements into query php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i'm working on admin panel form and i have a problem in connect form page to mysql .. i made table name : `main_settigns` and i'm working with MVC .. this is the form controller :-

```
enter code here
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Update")
 {
   $mainsettings['site_name'] =  $_POST['site_name'];
   $mainsettings['site_url'] =  $_POST['site_url'];
   $mainsettings['site_desc'] =  $_POST['site_desc'];
   $mainsettings['site_email'] =  $_POST['site_email'];
   $mainsettings['site_tags'] =  $_POST['site_tags'];
   $mainsettings['site_homapanel'] =  $_POST['site_homapanel'];
   $mainsettings['fb'] =  $_POST['fb'];
   $mainsettings['tw'] =  $_POST['tw'];
   $mainsettings['yt'] =  $_POST['yt'];
   $mainsettings['username'] =  $_POST['username'];
   try {
   include 'models/Arageek.php';
   include 'models/Add.php';
  $addmMainSettings = new Add($mainsettings, "main_settigns");

  if($addmMainSettings == TRUE)
  {
      echo 'successfully Added';
  }

 } 
catch (Exception $exc)
 {
   echo $exc->getMessage();
 }
 }
 else
 {
try {
   include 'models/Arageek.php';
   include 'models/Display.php';
   $data = new Display("main_settigns");
   $displayData = $data->getData();
} catch (Exception $exc)
{
    echo $exc->getMessage();

}

include 'views/v_mainSettings.php';
 }
  ?>
```

this is the model page :-

```
enter code here

<?php

 /* add class
  * insert the data into mysql database
  * @author Dev.Yasser
  */
 class Add extends Arageek
 {
private $data;
private $tablename;
private $cxn;


public function __construct($data, $tablename)  
{
if(is_array($data))
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->tablename = $tablename;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Error: the data must be in an array .");
}

$this->connectToDB();
$this->AddData($this->data);

$this->close();

  }
// insert the data into the table
function AddData($data)
    {
    foreach ($data as $key=> $value) 
    {
    $keys[] = $key;
    $values[] = $value;
    }
    $tblKeys = implode($keys, ",");
    $dataValues = '"'.  implode($values, '","') .'"';

    $query = "INSERT INTO $this->tablename ($tblKeys) VALUES ($dataValues)";

    if($sql = mysql_query($query))    
    {
            return TRUE;
    }
            else {
        throw new Exception("Error: Can not excute the query");
        return FALSE;
    }
    }


}



 ?>
```

and the parent class :-

```
enter code here

<?php


class Arageek {

private $cxn;


 function connectToDB()
{
    include 'models/Database.php';
    $vars = "include/vars.php";
    $this->cxn=new Database($vars);
}

 function close()
{
    $this->cxn->close();
}

}


?>
```

the result after submit the form is : "Error: Can not excute the query"

Comment: Is the "settigns" typo on purpose?

Comment: yes, does it make any difference ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). That said, have you actually checked the `$query` variable before you execute it? Echo it out!

Comment: `echo $query;` and see if `implode` works correctly